# WebStorm Vue-i18n, anyway to get editor autocompletion support?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, vue-i18n

I'm localizing a webapp using **vue-i18n**. Is there anyway to get WebStorm to recognize strings in a function prefixed with `$t` as a dot notation path reference?

`$t('messages.some.key')`

in my en.js file which looks like:

```
exports defaults {
   messages: {
      some: {
        key: "Foo"
      }
   }
}
```

It would be nice if it provided me with autocomplete and also syntax highlighting if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: You probably should fire issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question but still unanswered... For those who have been looking for it and ended up here (like me), meanwhile there is a plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12981-i18n-support (https://github.com/nyavro/i18nPlugin)

See https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/tooling.html#i18nplugin-intellij-platform for more information how to configure the plugin.